# Unresolved References in PyCharm Running Virtual Environment

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

I'm running a project in PyCharm with a virtual environment. The set up of the directories are as follows

- Folder A

  - venv
  - Folder C

    - Folder D

      - Folder E

        - apps

Folder A is is set as sources root, and venv is set as library root.

The issue I'm having is that imports from files found in directories under the venv folder are showing the error 'Unresolved reference' and I'm unable to ctrl-click go to declaration on any of them. The project still runs fine. Imports from files in Folder E are resolved as well as things such as math, os, operator, etc. and so are imports from django, which are found in directories under the venv folder.

I have my python interpreter pointing at ...\venv\Scripts\python.exe The packages I'm trying to use are listed in the table under Settings > Project Interpreter.

Things I've tried so far .

1. Invalidate caches & restart
2. Delete and re-add my existing interpreter
3. Delete .idea folder and re-add project
4. Delete venv and my interpreter and make a new one with inherit global site-packages checked
5. Number 4 but with the option unchecked
6. Fresh install of PyCharm
7. Different combinations for folders marked as sources, or excluded
8. Combinations of all of these

This isn't isolated to just one project either, it is an issue across all of my projects.
Further this has not once worked since I installed PyCharm.

Hopefully I've provided enough information.
Thanks!

Additional information:

My cwd on the CLI when I run it is Folder A.
It runs without errors.
I run it with `Folder_C.Folder_D.manage runserver`

I add the environment through Settings > Project Interpreter. I select add from the settings wheel, select virtual environment, then add from there.

venv is marked as excluded in Project Structure

Comment: When you run with command line, from which point (directory) you start? This should be your "base source folder". Doest it run without errors? On your description I do not see: set the project environment, nor how you set up to run the code. Could you add such info?

Comment: Please check that `venv` is marked as excluded, Right Click - Mark As - Excluded, sounds strange but it will be processed anyway as interpreter is located in it